# Building a simple Qt UI Application using CMake creates blurry UI

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake, qtgui

I have created a simple Qt application with only a MainWindow and a Button. When I build it in Qt using `Qmake` it works fine and UI is good as well. On other hand if build it using CMake it works fine but application UI is blurry.

Could anybody please let me know how to fix it. Thank you.

**UI of Application Generated with `QMake`**-
[image]
**UI of Application Generated with `CMake`**
[image]

My `CmakeList.txt` File

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(MyProject)

find_package(Qt5Widgets 5.9 PATHS /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1)
find_package(OpenGL)
#find_package(IOKit PATHS /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_library(mainwindow mainwindow.cpp)
target_link_libraries (mainwindow Qt5::Widgets)

#set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE YES)
add_executable(MyProject MACOSX_BUNDLE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (MyProject mainwindow ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

Project Structure-

[image]

My Machine Configuration-

[image]

Comment: Is it only "blurry" on a Retina display?  Is the blurriness simply that it's not running in @2x mode?

Comment: @Ssswift Unfortunately, I am not sure of that as I have not tested with non-retina Mac. In that case what would be the fix, I can try if that can fix the issue.

Comment: CMake is just a (meta) build system. It, in itself, cannot be responsible for making your app blurred.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Agreed! The point here is- I believe there must be some Qt GUI specific configuration needs to be done in `CMakeLists.txt` to make it work properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!

I think creating bundle for MacOS needs following keys to be set in `Info.plist` file as it mentioned [here](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11/).

Creating a custom `Info.plist` file with adding following keys solved the issue-

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>NSApplication</string>
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<string>True</string>
```

To add custom `Info.plist` add following line in `CMakeLists.txt` file-

```
# Set a custom plist file for the app bundle
set_target_properties(MyProject PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST <dir>/Info.plist)
```

Comment: use `<true/>` for booleans, not `<string>True</string>`